# SAS: robust regression and output coefficients, t values and adj R squares

Tags: sas, regression, robust

I am running robust regression by group in SAS .
My data is like

```
  id    stock     date     stock_liq      market_liq
   1     VOD     1/5/2016     0.03          0.02
   1     VOD     2/5/2016     0.04          0.025
  ...    ...        ...        ...          ...
   2     SAB     1/5/2016     0.31          0.02
   2     SAB     1/5/2016     0.31          0.02
  ...    ...        ...        ...          ...
```

Its a panel data and each stock has a unique ID. **I want to run robust regression by ID and I want to output the coefficients, t values and adj-R squares.**

My code is:

```
proc robustreg data=have outest= want noprint;
model stock_liq=market_liq  ;
by id;
run;
```

However I don't think the code runs properly. SAS just stops running and the log gives me

```
 "Error: Too many parameters in the model".
```

Can anyone advise ? Thank you !

Comment: I think the **By** statement must be before **model** statement.

Comment: Hi, Thanks, It works.  Could you let me know how to output t-value from a robust regression ?

Comment: Maybe this would be of use https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63347/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_rreg_sect013.htm

Comment: So, did it work?

Comment: @pinegulf   YES, THANKS

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is a bit off. Also the requested outputs can be added:

```
proc robustreg data=have outest= want noprint;
    by id;
    model stock_liq=market_liq  ;
    output out=output_sas 
       p=stock_liq
       r=stock_liqresid ;
run;
```

See more on the output options from [documentation](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63347/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_rreg_sect013.htm)